# Extracting a string from a specific position from a DAT file

Tags: string, vba, position, extract, binaryfiles

Hello everyone I'm new in VBA programming but I've used Excel for 2 years, I want to build a program that can extract a String (30 pos long) from an specific position of every line (pos 15) and place it into a cell in my worksheet, sounds easy but I need to extract every string of every line from a DAT archive that contains 22,157,838 records, I have to place 1,048,575 records on a column and Offset to the start of the next column, I really appreciate any help, here's my code:

```
Sub FirstMACR_ATV()
    Dim myFile As String
    textline As String
    CUENTA As String
    myFile = "C:\Users\s3850630\Desktop\EXPMST.dat"
    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        CUENTA = Mid(textline, 15, 30)
End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What are you going to do with the result? PowerPivot can take care of rows over Excel's limit. You can use the Sub just to create a text file with the `CUENTA` values then use PowerPivot to analyze data from the that text file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is just like Tim Williams's only different (great minds think like mine).  I added an `Application.StatusBar` message to ease the mind of the poor guy that is going to have to wait for this to process.  I also write all the data at once.

You might want to experiment with the `MAX_ROWS_PER_COLUMN`.  100K might perform better than 1000k (for daily use, the processing time will be roughly the same).  In any case, a 316 MB Excel file is not Ideal.  I recommend using a database.

```
Sub FirstMACR_ATV()
    Dim t As Long: t = Timer
    Const MAX_ROWS_PER_COLUMN AS Long = 1000000
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim myFile As String, textline As String
    Dim results() As Variant
    myFile = "C:\Users\s3850630\Desktop\EXPMST.dat"

    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        r = r + 1

        If r > MAX_ROWS_PER_COLUMN Or c = 0 Then
            c = c + 1
            r = 1
            ReDim Preserve results(1 To MAX_ROWS_PER_COLUMN, 1 To c)
        End If

        If r = 50000 Then Application.StatusBar = "Processing record #" & (r * c) & " " & Round(Timer - t, 2) & " Seconds"
        results(r, c) = Mid(textline, 15, 30)
    Loop
    Close #1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested...

```
Sub FirstMACR_ATV()

    Const RECS_PER_COL As Long = 1000000

    Dim myFile As String, arr(), i As Long
    Dim textline As String, c As Range

    ReDim arr(1 To RECS_PER_COL, 1 To 1)

    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("destination").Range("A1")

    myFile = "C:\Users\s3850630\Desktop\EXPMST.dat"

    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        i = i + 1
        arr(i, 1) = Mid(textline, 15, 30)

        'hit row limit?
        If i = RECS_PER_COL Then
            c.Resize(RECS_PER_COL, 1).Value = arr 'Dump data
            ReDim arr(1 To RECS_PER_COL, 1 To 1)
            i = 0
            Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)   'move over one column
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1

    If i > 0 Then c.Resize(i, 1).Value = arr

End Sub
```